# Application is unfortunately stopped GraphView

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-graphview

AT runtime it shows Fatal exception and also gives java.lang.NoClassFound Exception.
How can i run this code.

Both XML and Activity classess are given below.
Please Help us.......

In Eclipse it does not show any error But whwn i run the applicaion it "Unfortunately Stops Working".

XML LayOut File

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:id="@+id/layout" >

</LinearLayout>
```

Main Activity of application

```
package com.example.graphview1;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;

import com.jjoe64.graphview.GraphView;
import com.jjoe64.graphview.GraphView.GraphViewData;
import com.jjoe64.graphview.GraphViewSeries;
import com.jjoe64.graphview.LineGraphView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    LinearLayout layout;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        layout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.layout);
        GraphViewSeries exampleSeries = new GraphViewSeries(new GraphViewData[] {  
                  new GraphViewData(1, 40)  
                  , new GraphViewData(2, 12)  
                  , new GraphViewData(3, 7)
                  , new GraphViewData(2, 8)
                  , new GraphViewData(2, 10)
                  , new GraphViewData(3, 26)
                  , new GraphViewData(1, 37)
                  , new GraphViewData(1, 53)
                  , new GraphViewData(3, 253)

            });  

            GraphView graphView = new LineGraphView(  
                  this // context  
                  , "Job Status Graph" // heading  
            );  
            graphView.addSeries(exampleSeries); // data  

            layout.addView(graphView);  
    }
}
```

Comment: Which class can't be found?